# Select two largest values of a column

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following columns

```
Store_ID, Item_ID, Sales_Amount
```

I need to retrieve the two top selling items for each store. Someone have an idea or suggestion for this problem?

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT mytable.Store_ID, mytable.Sales_Amount
FROM mytable
    LEFT JOIN mytable table2 ON mytable.Store_ID = table2.Store_ID 
    AND mytable.Sales_Amount <= table2.Sales_Amount
GROUP BY mytable.Store_ID, mytable.Sales_Amount HAVING COUNT(mytable.*) <= 2;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Matt and everyone who answered!

Comment: By the way Matt, I'm using SQL in SAS.

Comment: LEFT JOINing on an inequality to solve n-per-group problems should work in just about everything not just mysql. Although you'll still to include the table aliases in the Select, Group by and having clauses.